# PHP fatal memory error installing Laravel cashier

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-cashier

I tried to install laravel cashier with the comand `composer require laravel/cashier` but after a while I've got this error

`PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar://C:/composer/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php on line 52`

how can put I more memory available for this process, or solve this error?

Edit: my laptop memory is 8Gb

Comment: What is your memory size?

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors

Comment: If you have a lot of dependencies, you might need to remove some, run `composer update`, then add them back, update again, then try to add the new library

Answer (score 0):

You should increase your memory_limit directive, from php.ini or add this line in your script

```
ini_set("memory_limit", "256M");
```

EDIT
Since it is composer, you can only edit php.ini directive. Anyway 1.5gb to install a lib is strange ( I though initially it was 160mb, my fault ) and it is not recommended to increase memory limit to GBs, try also to update your composer.

Comment: 1) This is composer, not straight PHP, and 2) it's running out at 1.5G so 256M is way too low

Comment: @aynber, yes you are right, it is 1.5G, I initially though it was 160mb, I've edited my answer.